# SqlDataAdapter->SelectCommand and using Print in SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter, output

MSSQL has a PRINT command which lets me write output from stored procedures and sql text queries. The problem is that this output is not returned when calling through SqlDataAdapater using Fill method.

I am not sure why but if Print is not possible to use then maybe there is an alternative pipe:ing output to result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, anything that you want needs to be returned with the 'result'.

You could in theory use an OUT parameter and add additional information to this.

[Using a Stored Procedure with Output Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378108%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`PRINT` output is received via the connection's `InfoMessage` event. So *technically* you could collect them separately and merge. However, I would advise you to use either `SELECT` or `out` parameters / the `return` value, to communicate information from a command.

Answer (score 1):

You simply get the data from the **`select`** command or you can use the **`return`**

simple example

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE checkstate @param varchar(11)
AS
IF (SELECT StateProvince FROM Person.vAdditionalContactInfo WHERE ContactID = @param) = 'WA'
    RETURN 1
ELSE
    RETURN 2;
GO
```

here you can use **`select`** also instead of **`return`**